# Undefined control sequence tables with figures

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table with figures in them but LateX keeps giving me the same error over and over again. This is the text I'm using:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | m{5cm} | m{5cm} | }
    \hline
    Shape & Area & Moments of Inertia \\ \hline\hline
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{figure/circle}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    %\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $A=\piR^2$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    & 
    %\begin{minipage}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\frac{1}{4}\piR^2$
        \item $I_{yz}=0$
        \item $I_p=\frac{1}{2}\piR^4$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    \\ 
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{figure/thincircle}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    %\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $A=2\piRt$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    & 
    %\begin{minipage}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\piR^3t$
        \item $I_{yz}=0$
        \item $I_p=2\piR^3t$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}     
        \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sectional variables for circle and hollow circle}\label{tab:inertiasum}
\end{table}
```

Hope anyone can help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What error?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, you can format code sections using the `{}` button, see my edit) I assume `\piR^4$` should be `\pi R^4$` to refer to pi. (Please always post _complete_ small documents not just fragments)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two two errors in your LaTeX. First, in the equations, `\pi` runs into what follows. You need to either enclose it in brackets `{\pi}` or leave a space afterwards. Otherwise, TeX thinks you're calling an underfined macro called `\piR`.

Second, you're missing a line break before your final horizontal rule. You actually want the horizontal rule to start on the next line, but you're calling it in the final column of the final row in the table.

I'm not sure if there are any problems related to the figures. You haven't included them, so I commented out those lines in your code. Here's a working example with the figures lines commented out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | m{5cm} | m{5cm} | }
    \hline
    Shape & Area & Moments of Inertia \\ \hline\hline
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
%      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{figure/circle}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    %\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $A={\pi}R^2$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    & 
    %\begin{minipage}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\frac{1}{4}\pi R^2$
        \item $I_{yz}=0$
        \item $I_p=\frac{1}{2}\pi R^4$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    \\ \hline
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
%      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{figure/thincircle}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    %\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $A=2\pi Rt$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    & 
    %\begin{minipage}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\pi R^3t$
        \item $I_{yz}=0$
        \item $I_p=2\pi R^3t$
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}     
       \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sectional variables for circle and hollow circle}\label{tab:inertiasum}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And my output:

[image: Output for included code]